# Joomla 1.0.15 to 1.5 Migrator component

Tags: joomla

Does anyone know where I can find the Joomla 1.0.15 to 1.5 Migrator component that's supposed to be here? [Pasamio Project's FRS site](http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/pasamioprojects/frs/). For some reason I just get "Permission denied" when I follow that link.

I realize that this is an OLD version, which is why I'm trying to get rid of it.

Thanks!

Comment: Joomla! 1.5 is really old too. Maybe that's why the component is not available anymore. You should consider to make a whole new website using Joomla 2.5 or 3.1 and migrate the content and extensions manually.

Comment: @TIIUNDER: If you want to migrate 1.0 to a current version, you have to go through 1.5. So the question is absolutely valid.

Answer (score 13):

Looks like the code is no longer accessible; there is an [item on the tracker](http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/tracker/?action=TrackerItemEdit&tracker_item_id=30281) regarding this.

I put a copy of it into my dropbox, where it will stay accessible as long as I have an account there. You are welcome to [download it from there](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/37264643/migrator-1.5.zip).

Comment: Thanks for the dropbox download. I needed it too :)

Comment: It can also be found in a Joomla Forum post: http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=689562#p2965112

Comment: You saved me! Two years later!! 

I love you.

Comment: grateful for the dropbox link ;)